# Is there a default css layout for developers out there?

Tags: css, layout, default

Currently i'm coding a webpage (or the functionality of a webpage) but the design is not ready now. 
Is there a "Standard CSS Layout" somewhere out there which i could include to make my application look a little bit nicer? 
It's importand that i NOT have to give every element a special class.
Thanks in advice....

Comment: are you asking if there is a default website ? all html elements have defauly styling. Anything custom you need to define.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using three sheets offered in Yahoo's [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/).

Quoting their documentation.

- [Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/): removes and neutralizes the inconsistent default styling of HTML elements, creating a level playing field across A-grade browsers and providing a sound foundation upon which you can explicitly declare your intentions.
- [Fonts CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/fonts/): The foundational YUI Fonts CSS file offers cross-browser typographical normalization and control.
- [Base CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/base/): an optional CSS file that complements YUI's core CSS foundation (Reset, Fonts, and Grids). While Reset removes and neutralizes the inconsistent default styling of HTML elements, Base applies a consistent style foundation for common HTML elements across A-grade browsers.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the most frequently used grid systems used for layout: http://960.gs/

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's included in the browser. The font is Times New Roman, the background is typically grey or white, and elements revert to their default style settings as described in the standard.

**Edit:**

As described here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

Answer (score 0):

Before you jump into using either YUI or 960 or any other "css framework", what are you actually trying to do... lay out a page (put your blocks of text and images at certain places on the page) or are you just trying to make the text itself look better?

Your question is vague enough that a css framework is likely overkill for what you're trying to accomplish.